# Can you play Portal 2 Coop with one Windows PC and one Mac?

Tags: portal-2

Is it possible to play coop with a windows computer and a Mac? Just wondering before I buy the game.

Comment: wha... _you haven't bought the game yet??_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Yes it is possible](http://uk.ps3.ign.com/articles/116/1161617p1.html). It is even possible between a PC or Mac and a PS3.

Answer (score 3):

It does work indeed. I have played several times on both ends. The only issues we were having were due to crowded servers from valve, as they host/initiate the coop session.